# Search bar with dropdown options and function call

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a search bar with 2 options (as dropdown list) and ONLY if user selects S1 it should call a highligthme () function  and should display  .

but if user selects S2 it should not call this function and my code is calling this function on both selections from drop down list ?

Below is my code. Please guide what am i doing wrong?

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span id="search_concept">ACTION</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-dropdown" role="menu" >
        <li id="S1"><a href="#" >search 1</a></li>
        <li id="S2"><a href="#">search 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="search_param"  id="search_param">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="Search" id="txtBoxSearchKey" placeholder="Select Action from list " size="20" >
    <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btnSearch"onclick="orderSelector(document.getElementById('txtBoxSearchKey').value,document.getElementById('search_param').textContent)">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
     </button></span>
    <span class="result-count" ></span>
</div>
```

CSS being used is:

```
/* Style to create scroll bar in dropdown */
.scrollable-dropdown{
height: auto;
max-height:320px;  /* Increase / Decrease value as per your need */
overflow-x: hidden;
}

<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add a copy of the css code

Comment: updated CSS too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you missing the event listeners on your buttons clicks .

Another think I changed was to give the elements ID's so we can add events to them . 
I also used they CSS libraries that come with bootstrap

In order to get the popup to display we have to add the

```
show
```

class to the element

Here is the working code in the snippet It shows the popup and runs a function called highlight if S1 is clicked ...

I trust this helps

```js
//first thing is to get the action button click event


var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
dropdown.addEventListener("click", display);

function display(e) {

  var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
  if (foo.classList.contains('show')){
  foo.classList.remove('show');
  }
  else{
  foo.classList.add('show');
  }
}
// now to run your highlight me function 


var s1 = document.getElementById('S1');
s1.addEventListener("click", highligthme)

function highligthme() {

 console.log('this does whatever hilightme does ')
foo.classList.remove('show');
}
```

```css
.scrollable-dropdown {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 320px;
  /* Increase / Decrease value as per your need */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id='dropdown'>
        <span id="search_concept">ACTION</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-dropdown " id='foo' role="menu ">
      <li id="S1"><a href="#">search 1</a></li>
      <li id="S2"><a href="#">search 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="search_param" id="search_param">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Search" id="txtBoxSearchKey" placeholder="Select Action from list " size="20">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btnSearch"
     onclick="orderSelector(document.getElementById('txtBoxSearchKey').value,
     document.getElementById('search_param').textContent)">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <span class="result-count"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much, but it still is calling highlightme() on S1 and S2 seleciton.

Comment: THat means that there is an event listener somewhere else in your code . not displayed here ... Run a full text search for it in all files related to your project